# How to restore icons to default in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, icons, restore, reset

Installed a theme by "[ZeusOSX](http://zeusosx.deviantart.com/#/d2k45yw)". The problem is that I removed all the files, copied back the dll's, did a `sfc /scannow` (which still found some problem) and now I *still* have the MAC like folder icons.

How can one reset them back to the original state ?

Comment: Noth answer = No use. System restore would set my files back also (thats something I do not want); the other option.. I can press it , but nothing happens. I also noticed it, mostly folders I made BACK THEN have that icon... beats me.. :/

Comment: System Restore _should_ not affect any data files - only program files and system files updated since the Restore Point

Comment: Hmm. Some wonderful cleaner app cleaned out my points (even assigned 50gb for them). Guess I'll try to create a new user and copy there my files. Hope it works. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys for this and *really*, thank for your answers. After several reboots, sfc /scannow and so on, the icons got back into the original state. Sadly these are good solution, yet they didn't help here. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/system-restore) to a point previous to when you installed ZeusOSX.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to restore the default folder icon:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/23825-folder-icon-change-windows-7-default-folder-icon.html

Comment: Thank you for the link. I didn't have the reg key, nor the string. So what is the default? What should I set? :/

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend following this guide, https://superuser.com/a/523172/181734 since none of the answers here are correct and relevant to the question asked.

Comment: Thank you James. It was the icons. Maybe I should've removed the IconCache... which I found later on. (CCleaner can remove this file.) But I WON'T EVER install Windows 7 themes, UX patches and whatnot. All it results is chaos and destruction.